# rails4 fail creating relation can't write unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have the following code

db:

```
create_table :parties do |t|
    t.integer :host_id
    t.integer :guests
    t.string  :description
end
```

user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :host_parties, class_name: 'Party'

end
```

party:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :host, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'host_id'

    attr_accessor :user_id
end
```

parties_controller:

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @party = current_user.host_parties.create(party_params)
    end

    private
    def party_params
      params.require(:party).permit(:host_id, :guests, :description)
    end
 end
```

for some reason the create fails with:can't write unknown attribute `user_id'

how can I make rails treat the User.id as host_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `has_many` relationship within your `User` model, you need to specify the `foreign_key` as the default value is `user_id`.

The following should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :host_parties, class_name: Party, foreign_key: :host_id
end
```